# How to make a multline form in pdf that text flows through?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm working on a form that could be filled out manually, or submitted digitally.
Here's the issue:

When submitting digitally, I have certain forms that have 3 lines for the user to fill out a significant chunk of text. Instead of it compiling on one line using the 'multiline' checkbox in acrobat, can i have it automatically wrap to the next line as the user types to the end of the previous line?

Basically, there are the normal lines which need to be there. I'm wondering if anyone has a script (and how to implement) that would allow when a  line is full, to jump to the next line down, flowing the text to the next line.

Here's a screenshot of how the form sections look:[image]
If anyone has run across this, any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So you want a form that has 3 black lines so a person that prints it can see where to write but those 3 black lines to be linked as though they are one large content box? This is correct?

Comment: Hi Ryan, just posted a pic of what i'm after. Basically, i'm trying to flow the text across these lines as though it was one content box. You're spot on. I imagine there may be a script for this, but I'm clueless as to how to implement it at this time.
Thanks for replying.

Comment: I have never created a PDF with such needs but a quick tought from similar stuff(in ActionScript or HTML/CSS, JavaScript) is that maybe you are using Single Line text inputs... instead of something like Text Box(supports multiline text) ..but thats just a guess.. I'll have to try this and come back with an answer

Comment: This last answer works, but when typing to the end and appears on the next line down, it seems to "eat" a letter. For example, if the last word on the first line is "simple" but it only ends at "sim", it goes to the next line but it only shows "le" and the "p" doesn't appear. I would have to go back erase and retype the "ple". It's really strange, but I guess you can't have everything/

Answer (score 3):

This works but can be a bit time-consuming. This is assuming you're still editing in the Forms function in Adobe Acrobat. I know this works for Acrobat 10.

Highlight/select text field that continuation will be starting from.

Right-Click and Open **Properties /**
**Appearance /** 
Set an *absolute font size (not auto)*

**Options /**
uncheck *"multi-line"* and *"scroll long text"*

**Format /**
Select:  **Custom /**

Paste the following into **Custom Keystroke Script** (bottom field, note "edit" button on the right):

```
if ( event.fieldFull || event.willCommit ) this.getField("*name of next
field to continue in*").setFocus();
```

*Repeat* this for every field that will need any continuation, ensuring that each target field is named correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want. Acrobat forms can not "continue" text into another input area or line. So your input area needs to encompass the entire area for input and it must be rectangular.

You are better off creating header text for text areas rather than lines of text. This is merely due to how Acrobat forms work. They can't read the partial lines and adjust input to accommodate for them.

So create your form assuming the data to be input will **always** start in the top left corner of the text area.

Then it is a simple matter to check the "Multi-Line" option for the form element in Acrobat.

[image: multi-line]

Answer (score -1):

```
var x=this.getField ("Text73");

if (event.fieldFull) {
    getField("Text74").setFocus();
}
```

This code works with newer Adobe Readers (I have 2017). Follow the instructions as said in previous post but use this code instead. Replace Text73 with the name of the field you're in and replace Text74 with the name of the field where you want the text to continue.

Comment: Could you add some explanation, perhaps what to do with this script?